# Transform casual list into dependently typed list in Coq

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I have following definition of list in Coq:

```
Variable A : Set.
Variable P : A -> Prop.
Hypothesis P_dec : forall x, {P x}+{~(P x)}.

Inductive plist : nat -> Set :=
   pnil : plist O
  | pcons : A -> forall n, plist n -> plist n
  | pconsp : forall (a:A) n, plist n -> P a -> plist (S n)
  .
```

It describes "list of elements of type `A` where at least `n` of them fulfill predicate `P`".

My task is to create function that will convert casual list into `plist` (with maximum possible `n`). My attempt was to first count all elements that match `P` and then set the output type according to the result:

```
Fixpoint pcount (l : list A) : nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => O
  | h::t => if P_dec h then S(pcount t) else pcount t
  end.

Fixpoint plistIn (l : list A) : (plist (pcount l)) :=
  match l with
  | nil => pnil
  | h::t => match P_dec h with
          | left proof => pconsp h _ (plistIn t) proof
          | right _ => pcons h _ (plistIn t) 
          end
  end.
```

However, I get an error in the line with `left proof`:

```
Error:
In environment
A : Set
P : A -> Prop
P_dec : forall x : A, {P x} + {~ P x}
plistIn : forall l : list A, plist (pcount l)
l : list A
h : A
t : list A
proof : P h
The term "pconsp h (pcount t) (plistIn t) proof" has type
 "plist (S (pcount t))" while it is expected to have type
 "plist (pcount (h :: t))".
```

The problem is that Coq cannot see that `S (pcount t)` equals `pcount (h :: t)` knowing that `P h`, which was already proven. I cannot let Coq know this truth.

How to define this function correctly? Is it even possible to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dependent pattern-matching, as the result type `plist (pcount (h :: t))` depends on whether `P_dec h` is `left` or `right`.

Below, the keyword `as` introduces a new variable `p`, and `return` tells the type of the whole `match` expression, parameterized by `p`.

```
Fixpoint plistIn (l : list A) : (plist (pcount l)) :=
  match l with
  | nil => pnil
  | h::t => match P_dec h as p return plist (if p then _ else _) with
          | left proof => pconsp h (pcount t) (plistIn t) proof
          | right _ => pcons h _ (plistIn t) 
          end
  end.
```

The type `plist (if p then _ else _)` must be equal to `plist (pcount (h :: t))` when substituting `p := P_dec h`. Then in each branch, say `left proof`, you need to produce `plist (if left proof then _ else _)` (which reduces to the left branch).

It's a bit magical that Coq can infer what goes in the underscores here, but to be safe you can always spell it out: `if p then S (pcount t) else pcount t` (which is meant to exactly match the definition of `pcount`).

Comment: Could you explain why `return if p then plist (S (pcount t)) else plist (pcount t) with` doesn't work here, or should I ask another question?

Comment: That's fine here. This doesn't work because when checking whether `if P_dec h then plist (S (pcount t)) else plist (pcount t)` is equal to `plist (if P_dec h then S (pcount t) else pcount t)`, the typechecker only considers beta-equivalence, but these two terms are not beta-equivalent. You may prove `(if ... then pcount ... else pcount ... ) = pcount (if ... then ... else ...)` as a theorem, but this `=` ("propositional equality") is a much weaker notion of equality than beta-equivalence (or more precisely, "definitional equality") which is used by the typechecker.